# How to implement the regret matching algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, game-theory, learning-theory

My question is the following: How to calculate the regret in practice?

I am trying to implement the regret matching algorithm but I do not understand how to do it.

- First, I have $n$ players with the joint action space $\mathcal{A}=\{a_0, a_1,\cdots,a_m\}^n.$
- Then, I fix some period $T$. The action set $A^t\in\mathcal{A}$ is the action set chosen by players at time $t$. After the period $T$ (every player has chosen an action). So I get $u_i(A^t)$.
- Now the regret of player $i$ of not playing action $a_i$ in the past is: (here $A^t\oplus a_i$ denotes the strategy set obtained if player $i$ changed its strategy from $a'_i$ to $a_i$)
  $$\max\limits_{a_i\in A_i}\left\{\dfrac{1}{T}\sum_{t\leqslant T}\left(u_i(A^t\oplus a_i )-u_i(A^t)\right)\right\}.$$
  I do not understand how to calculate this summation. Why there is a max over the action $a_i\in A_i$? Should I calculate the regret of all actions in $A_i$ and calculate the maximum? Also, In Hart's paper, the maximum is $\max\{R, 0\}$. Why is there such a difference?

  I mean if the regret was:  $\dfrac{1}{T}\sum_{t\leqslant T}\left(u_i(A^t\oplus a_i )-u_i(A^t)\right),$
  the calculation would be easy for me.

The regret is defined in the following two papers [1] (see page 4, equation (2.1c)) and [2] (see page 3, section I, subsection B).

---

1. [A simple adaptive procedure leading to correlated equilibrium](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~ninamf/LGO10/hartmascolell.pdf) by S. Hart et al (2000)
2. [Distributed algorithms for approximating wireless network capacity](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~mdinitz/papers/DistributedCapacity.pdf) by Michael Dinitz (2010)

I would like to get some helps from you. Any suggestions step by step how to implement such an algorithm please?

Comment: Assuming I understand the notation correctly, the expression without the $\max$ just defines the negative impact the player experiences with his current strategy $a_i'$ compared to one specific other strategy $a_i$. Now the $\max$ just takes the maximum negative impact the player experiences compared to all other possible strategies. Example: paying for your dinner with your XBox is only slightly worse than paying for it with your TV. But paying for your dinner with your XBox is far worse than the best other strategy, which is just paying the 20\$ the restaurant is charging you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index set of the max operation is $A_i$, the actions of player $i$. The formula says: take each such action $a_i \in A_i$ and compute its regret (with the sub-formula you say you can implement easily), and then take the maximum of those regrets.

The reason for the $\max(R,0)$ is that actions with negative regrets are performing *worse* than the action currently chosen.

To implement this in code, just set a temporary variable $t$ to be 0. Now loop through the actions one by one, and for each action $a$, compute its regret $r$, and set $t$ as $\max(r,t)$. Note that this approach includes the $\max(R,0)$ operation; to do this without that, set $t$ initially to $-\infty$.